# How to get the backend name created by kubernetes_ingress_v1?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, terraform-provider-gcp

Recently I've been using Terraform to replicate my local infrastructure on Google Cloud Platform.
I've already created a Google Kubernetes Engine that runs containerized applications (pods), and all of these pods are connected to a Kubernetes Service. I've also created an External HTPP Load Balancing using **kubernetes_ingress_v1**, as in the following snippet:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "external" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true

  metadata {
    name = "${var.mode}-quokka-ingress"
    namespace = "quokka"
    annotations = {
     "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "gce"
     "kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name" = "${var.mode}-server"
    }
  }
  spec {
    rule {
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service {
              name = "quokka-service"
              port {
                number = 8080
              }
            }
          }
            path = "/*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This resource is able to create a GCP Load Balancer and other resources, such as:

[image: Created Resources]

I want to create an autoscaling resource to scale up/down machines based on the number of requests that are received by the Google Cloud HTTPS/Load Balancer. Google Cloud provides a metric called **Backend Request Count**, that stores the number of requests served by backends of external HTTP(S) load balancer.

The metric name is = **loadbalancing.googleapis.com/https/backend_request_count**

I want to filter this particular Load Balancer and to do this I need to add filters such as the proxy name, forwarding rule name, backend target name, or backend name (I'm only interested in filtering with one these metrics).

By the documentation [kubernetes_ingress_v1](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/ingress_v1), it seems that it's not possible to access these metrics through the resource.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to access these metrics with terraform?

Comment: I can't test it out ATM so dropping a comment instead, does this help https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/horizontal_pod_autoscaler_v2 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue is not on the autoscaling part. The problem is finding a way to pass into the resource=kubernetes_horizontal_pod_autoscaler_v2, a filter referencing one of these: (proxy name, forwarding rule name, backend target name, or backend name) created by kubernetes_ingress_v1.
For instance, instead of match_labels = {lb_name = "test"}} as in the documentation, something like this: match_labels = {resource.labels.backend_target_name: "my-backend"}}

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way that kind of does the job done is parse the backend name out of the annotation that gets attached to the `Ingress` object once the backend is set up.

First define your ingress as usual:

```
resource "kubernete_ingress_v1" "external" {
  ...
}
```

Sometime later, once the GCE ingress controller processes the `Ingress` definition, it attaches the annotation to the `Ingress` object with the configured GCE backends:

```
# Pull the datastore with the specific annotation.
data "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "external" {
  metadata {
    name      = "reports-gce"
    annotations = {
      # Request the specific annotation.
      "ingress.kubernetes.io/backends" = "{}"
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_ingress_v1.external
  ]
}
```

Note that it might take some time (minutes) to have this annotation populated, so applying this terraform config is not idempotent, but is eventually consistent.

You can then generate a data source for every backend in the ingress:

```
data "google_compute_backend_service" "services" {
  for_each = {
    for service, status in jsondecode(data.kubernetes_ingress.external.metadata.0.annotations["ingress.kubernetes.io/backends"])
    :
    service => status
  if length(regexall(".*kube-system-default-http-backend.*", service)) == 0 }

  name = each.key
}
```